# Dúvida em relação a manipulação do Excel através da biblioteca pandas no PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a manipulação do Excel através da biblioteca pandas.

Primeiramente eu importo a biblioteca pandas, em seguida eu atribuo a uma variável o caminho que está a planilha.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\victo\Desktop\planilha_vendas\xlsx') # Caminho do arquivo
```

Só que depois de ter feito isso, não consigo utilizar os métodos da biblioteca pandas, conforme a imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma forma que encontrei para que os métodos ficassem disponível foi depois de ler o caminho, foi converter a variável em Data Frame, como está a seguir:

```
import pandas as pd #importa a biblioteca
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\victo\Desktop\planilha_vendas\xlsx') #Caminho do arquivo
df = pd.DataFrame(df) #Conversão para Data Frame
```

Na imagem logo abaixo, os métodos ficam disponível após ter feito isso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bem, a minha dúvida é porque no PyCharm os métodos só ficam disponível após fazer essa conversão no formato xlsx? Pois quando utilizei o google colab não precisou disso. As opções aparecem logo após a leitura da planilha.

Um fato que notei quando usei o Pycharm, é que quando o formato é CSV, não é necessário fazer este tipo de conversão. Os métodos são disponíveis logo após a leitura. E isto está me deixando intrigado.

Segue a imagem da CSV que mostra as opções logo após a leitura:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jennybc/gapminder/master/data-raw/04_gap-merged.tsv", sep= '\t')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso está me parecendo um erro na interface do PyCharm, provavelmente o lint dele está se perdendo.

Answer (score 0):

Vejo 2 situações:
A leitura em pandas já trás o arquivo como dataframe, ou seja, faça um print direto após sua leitura.

Sua descrição do arquivo está errada, você está com um "barra" no lugar do "ponto" no fim do caminho. O correto é 'C:\Users\victo\Desktop\planilha_vendas**.**xlsx'

Logo, seu código deve ficar assim:

`import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\victo\Desktop\planilha_vendas.xlsx')

print(df)`